# The sequence of functions converge on a dense subset

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Suppose that $f_n(x)$ is equicontinuous on $[a,b]$ and converges on a dense subset of $[a,b]$, prove: $f_n(x)$ converge uniformly on $[a,b]$.

My thought：Divide the interval into k parts by densely concentrated points so that the length of each part is not greater than $\delta$,and we can denote these points $a_1,\cdots,a_n$. Besides, suppose $f_n\to f$ on the dense subset. Hence,$\forall x\in [a,b]$,it must fall into one small part,which is to say $\exists a_i$,$|x-a_i|<\delta$. Therefore, $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq |f_n(x)-f_n(a_i)|+|f_n(a_i)-f(a_i)|+|f(a_i)-f(x)|~.$$ So the biggest problem is that I don’t know how to control $~|f(a_i)-f(x)|~$ for $~f(x)~$ may not be continuous.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please tell us any ideas or attempts you have made

Comment: I'm very sorry.Thank you for your suggestion! and I have re-edited the problem

Comment: No problem, thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: the argument you sketched would work for any $\delta$.  This usually means that you need to apply it with a particular strategic choice of $\delta$.

Hint 2: you have not yet used the equicontinuity hypothesis.

Hint 3: Hints 1 and 2 are related.

Comment: I know how to solve it！Thank u！！